# [Vue warn]: Property "articles" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to build a blog and while trying to fetch the data I am met with

[Vue warn]: Property "articles" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.

```
<template>
  <Header />
  <h1>This is the blog page!</h1>
  <div>
    <h1>Blog Posts</h1>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="article of articles" :key="article.slug">
        <NuxtLink :to="{ name: 'blog-slug', params: { slug: article.slug } }">
          <img :src="article.img" />
          <div>
            <h2>{{ article.title }}</h2>
            <p>by {{ article.author.name }}</p>
            <p>{{ article.description }}</p>
          </div>
        </NuxtLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
    const articles = await $content("articles")
      .only(["title", "description", "img", "slug", "author"])
      .sortBy("createdAt", "asc")
      .fetch();

    return {
      articles,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Trying to get a card item listing all of the articles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always remember to provide a default value in vue,and fech is better then asyncData.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      articles: {author:{}}
    }
  },
  async asyncData({
    $content,
    params
  }) {
    const articles = await $content("articles")
      .only(["title", "description", "img", "slug", "author"])
      .sortBy("createdAt", "asc")
      .fetch();

    return {
      articles,
    };
  },
};
```